# Add items to arraylist from RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and when I click on a value in the RecyclerView I want it to be added to an arraylist that will be sent to Firebase when I click done. Note that I need to be able to select multiple values and all need to be added to the same list. I have the value in listItem.getEmail but how do I get that value to the array and then added more values?

This is what I got:

Adapter.java

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull     PeopleToAddAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final PeopleToAdd listItem = mPeopleToAdd.get(position);
    holder.emailLbl.setText(listItem.getEmail());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked" + listItem.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPeopleToAdd.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView emailLbl;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        emailLbl = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailLbl);
    }
}
```

SetProject.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setCreate);
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createProject();
        }
    });
}
public void createProject(){
    final String subj = subject.getText().toString().trim();
    final String projectNm = projectName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String endDt = endDate.getText().toString();
    final String members = addPeople.getText().toString();



    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(subj) || TextUtils.isEmpty(projectNm) || TextUtils.isEmpty(endDt)) {

        if (subj.isEmpty()){
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.MyConstraintLayout), R.string.error_projecSubj,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (projectNm.isEmpty()){
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.MyConstraintLayout), R.string.error_projectName,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (endDt.isEmpty()){
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.MyConstraintLayout), R.string.error_projectDate,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

        return;
    }
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Creating new project...");
        mProgressDialog.show();

        DatabaseReference createNewProject = mPostDatabase.push();

        Map<String, String> dataToSave = new HashMap<>();
        dataToSave.put("subject", subj);
        dataToSave.put("projectName", projectNm);
        dataToSave.put("endDate", endDt);
        dataToSave.put("members", members);
        dataToSave.put("userid", mUser.getUid());
        dataToSave.put("creationDate", String.valueOf(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()));


        createNewProject.setValue(dataToSave);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

       startActivity(new Intent(SetProject.this, Main.class));
}
```

I hope that you understand what I'm looking for and that you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList();
Model model;

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked" + listItem.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            model = new Model(listItem.getEmail(),-----------);// add other fields also
            list.add(model);

        }

    });
```

Then send this list to firebase database.

Comment: I hope this has done the job. So accept the answer, so that it can be useful for others too.